# HTML: Cannot align image and text

Tags: html, css, email, outlook, windows-live

I have to build a signature, I made some test and it seems pretty okay in the browser.
But not in Windows Live Mail and Outlook 2010, it seems they interpretated HTML different from each other.

Here are some examples of my problem:

GMail:
[image]

Outlook 2010:
[image]

Windows Live Mail:
[image]

As you can see, I wasn't able to align the image (in Outlook and Windows Live Mail) with the text in the right to show as it should like in GMail image.

This is my code :

```
<hr>
<p style="color: gray;">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <a href="#"> <img src="file:///C:/images/logo.jpg" align="left" border="0"> </a>
        </td>

        <td>
            <b>Valter Henrique</b> <br>
            skype: valter_brain_set</br>
            email: <a href="#" style="text-decoration: none;color: #0056A2; ;">valter@brainset.com.br</a></br>
            fones: <b>11. 2094 6999<b> | 15. 9122 1822 
        </td>
    </tr>
</p>
<p style="padding-left:15px;">
    <font size=2 style="color: gray;">
        <a href="#" style="text-decoration: none;color: gray;">
            rua cel. irineu de castro, 188 - SP 
        </a> 
        <b>11. 2094 6999 </b> 
        <a href="#" style="text-decoration: none;color: gray">
            brainset.com.br
        </a>
    </font>
</p>
```

It seems that each email reader interpret the HTML pretty different from each other.
There's some way to fix this ?

Comment: Would it help if you changed the HTML to be error free?

Comment: @MrLister, what you mean by 'error free', sorry but I don't get it.

Comment: I mean that it shouldn't contain errors. Run it through the W3C validator! Then replace the first `<p>` and `</p>` by `<table>` and `</table>` respectively, decide on what to do with the `</br>`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

In the end this is my signature as I wish (thank you guys for the support):

```
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" CONTENT="text/html;charset=iso-8859-1">
<HTML>
    <HEAD></HEAD>
<BODY dir=ltr>
    <DIV dir=ltr>
        <DIV style="FONT-FAMILY: 'Arial'; COLOR: #000000; FONT-SIZE: 10pt">
            <DIV>&nbsp;</DIV>
            <DIV style="FONT-FAMILY: 'Arial'; COLOR: #000000; FONT-SIZE: 10pt">
                <STYLE type=text/css>
                    img{
                        border: 0;
                    }
                </STYLE>

                <DIV style="FLOAT: left">
                    <HR>

                    <TABLE style="COLOR: #000000">
                        <TBODY>
                            <TR>
                                <TD>
                                    <A href="http://www.brainset.com.br">
                                        <IMG style="BACKGROUND-IMAGE: none; BORDER-BOTTOM: 0px; BORDER-LEFT: 0px; PADDING-LEFT: 0px; PADDING-RIGHT: 0px; DISPLAY: inline; FLOAT: left; BORDER-TOP: 0px; BORDER-RIGHT: 0px; PADDING-TOP: 0px" title=logo border=0 alt=logo align=left src="file:///C:/BRAINSET/Email/assinatura/bs_innovo/valter_henrique/images/logo.jpg" width=156 height=76> 
                                    </A>
                                </TD>

                                <TD>
                                    <FONT size=2>
                                        <B>Valter Henrique</B> <BR>
                                        <FONT color=#666666>skype: valter_brain_set<BR>email: </FONT>
                                    </FONT>
                                    <A  style="COLOR: #0056a2; TEXT-DECORATION: none" href="mailto:valter@brainset.com.br">
                                        <FONT color=#666666 size=2>valter@brainset.com.br</FONT>
                                    </A>
                                    <BR>
                                    <FONT color=#666666>
                                        <FONT size=2>fones: 11. 2094-6999 | 15. 9122-1822</FONT> 
                                    </FONT>
                                </TD>
                            </TR>
                        </TBODY>
                    </TABLE>
                    <BR>
                    <STRONG>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; </STRONG>
                    <A style="COLOR: gray; TEXT-DECORATION: none" href="http://g.co/maps/upbwq">rua cel. irineu de castro, 188 - SP </A>
                    <B><FONT color=#0056A2>11. 2094 6999 </FONT><FONT color=#666666>|</FONT>&nbsp;</B>
                    <A style=" TEXT-DECORATION: none" href="http://www.brainset.com.br">
                        <FONT color=#0056A2>brainset.com.br</FONT> 
                    </A>
                </DIV>
            </DIV>
        </DIV>
    </DIV>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Answer (score 0):

To make the text align to top, try valign=top in the td:

```
 <td valign="top">
```

To make the text look the same, play around with the line-height and font properties in the CSS.